# Are Sobolev spaces on non-compact manifolds separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold that is not compact, is it true that the Sobolev spaces on $M$, $W^{k,p}(M)$,  still be separable (for $p < \infty$)?

Comment: Just curious: Are the Sobolev spaces separable when $M$ is compact? Note that the Holder spaces on $[0,1]$ are not separable.

Comment: In case conventions differ, could you please remind us of the definition of $W^{k,p}(M)$ and the norm on it? I assume that it means something like: derivatives up to and including order $k$ belong to $L^p$, with the norm being more or less the $L^p$ norm of the $k$'th derivative

Comment: Two comments: On a compact manifold you can take e.g. the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian to show $W^{k,2}(M)$ is separable. Presumably this also works for other $p$. On $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Hermite functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) are a basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I think that the span of the Hermite functions is dense in Schwartz functions, which shows that general $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is separable.

Comment: @YemonChoi That's exactly it.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Yes, as Otis wrote, the eigenfunctions of apprioriate elliptic operator will do.

Comment: @Kies: But on a non-compact manifold, elliptic operators such as the Laplace-Beltrami operator typically have no point spectrum, so there are no $L^2$ eigenfunctions.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I was referring to the compact case.

Comment: @OtisChodosh: The eigenfunctions of the Laplacian are a basis in $L^2$. Is it obvious that they are a basis in $W^{k,2}$ too? In principle, $W^{k,2}$ has many more open subsets than $L^2$, therefore its separability is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they are.

**Step 1** There exists measurable sections $e_1, e_2, \dotsc, e_m$, where $m = \dim M$, of $TM$ (measurable functions mapping a point $x$ to a vector of its tangent plane $T_xM$) such that for each $x \in M$, $e_1 (x), e_2 (x), \dotsc, e_m (x)$ forms an *orthonormal basis* of the tangent space $T_xM$.

In a neighbourhood of a given point, it is possible to construct such continuous sections by applying a Gram−Schmidt procedure. Such continuous maps can be patched together to form measurable sections.

**Step 2** 
For $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^m$, define to be $\partial^\alpha u$ to be the partial derivative in the basis $e_1, e_2, \dotsc, e_m$ 
The map
$$
  A: u \in W^{k, p} (M) \longmapsto A (u) = (\partial^\alpha u)_{\vert \alpha \vert \le k} \in L^p (M)^\nu,
$$
(where $\nu = \# \{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n : \vert \alpha \vert \le k\}$)
is continuous and its inverse defined on $A (W^{k, p} (M))$ is also continuous.

**Step 3** The subspace $A (W^{k, p} (M))$ is separable as a subset of the separable space $L^p (M)^\nu$ (since $M$ is a separable measure space because it is a second countable topological space). Since $A (W^{k, p} (M))$ is isomorphic to the space $W^{k, p} (M)$, the space  $W^{k, p} (M)$ is separable.

Comment: I guess by $\nu$ you mean the number of derivative components of order less than or equal to $k$.